# Entity Framework Core PostgreSQL EF.Functions.JsonTypeof

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

.Where(e => EF.Functions.JsonTypeof(e.Customer.GetProperty("Age")))

This syntax in https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cjsondocument not works!! show this error: cannot implicitly convert "string" to "bool"

Answer (score 1):

The sample syntax from the link is simply incomplete. `JsonTypeof` returns `string` an according to the link is mapped to [jsonb_typeof](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) which

> Returns the type of the outermost JSON value as a text string. Possible types are object, array, string, number, boolean, and null.

So the correct sample usage in `Where` clause would compare the return value of the method to a string containing one of the aforementioned values, for instance

```
.Where(e => EF.Functions.JsonTypeof(e.Customer.GetProperty("Age")) == "number")
```

Comment: Thanks @ivan-stoev, I've pushed a fix to the doc sample.

Comment: @jrocha76 Then you simply need different function -  `EF.Functions.JsonExists`, with sample usage from the link `.Where(e => EF.Functions.JsonExists(e.Customer, "Age")`